# Javascript Multiplication and Totals

Tags: javascript, math

I have several fields that people will put in loan totals... We'll say loan1 and loan2 just to keep it simple.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('loan1').addEvent('change', rekenen1);
$('loan2').addEvent('change', rekenen1);

});
function rekenen1(){
$('subtotal').value = Number($('loan1').value) + Number($('loan2').value) ;
}
```

When they enter the data I have it create a subtotal of all the loans. Now I want to make a grand total by taking 1% of the subtotal and adding 295 for the grand total. I need help making this into javascript.

So the equation:
loan1 + loan2 = subtotal

(subtotal*.01)+295=Grandtotal

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might not be using jQuery correctly there.  You're currently looking for elements that actually *are* a `<loan1>` and `<loan2>` tags, as opposed to tags that have an `id="loan1"` etc.  I think what you want is `$('#loan1')`, which will do the latter.

Comment: I'm so new to javascript that I don't know what to try honestly. I hate to sound ignorant but I've no idea what LukeGT is saying either :/

Comment: He is just saying you shoukd use `#loan1` to address the field with id `loan1`

Comment: also use the val() function of jQuery rather than just .value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have a field with id `grandtotal` you can just add a line to you rekenen1 function:

```
function rekenen1(){
    var subtotal = Number($('#loan1').val()) + Number($('#loan2').val());
    $('#subtotal').val(subtotal);
    $('#grandtotal').val(subtotal*0.01+295);
}
```

Edit:
I gone without saying that the addEvent have to change too:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#loan1').addEvent('change', rekenen1);
    $('#loan2').addEvent('change', rekenen1);

});
```

Changed rekenen1 function to use the [jquery val function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) too
changed the event

Comment: I can't get the grandtotal to populate in the form. I do have a field id as grandtotal but nothing is populating

Comment: Still nothing... [link]https://www.fedgrad.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=Registration2[/link] I've tried
`window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('#loan1').addEvent('change', rekenen1);
    $('#loan2').addEvent('change', rekenen1);

});
function rekenen1(){
    var subtotal = Number($('#loan1').val()) + Number($('#loan2').val());
    $('#subtotal').val(subtotal);
    $('#grandtotal').val(subtotal*0.01+295);
}`

Comment: you know, the link is not working: a jsfiddle working version: http://jsfiddle.net/HnJLB/ (changed the answer accordingly)

Comment: I was having a problem with it linking to the JS file. Everything works perfectly now. Was wondering if you knew a function that I could add that would remove commas and $ from the fields because they produce a NaN

Comment: @CarlV `"1,223.00$".replace(/[,$]/g,'');` maybe this or something similar https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace